# Nginx installed but command not found, how do I restart nginx

Tags: linux, nginx

I tried    `systemctl status nginx`
and got

```
 Unit nginx.service could not be found.
```

The server is currently running nginx

I use  `ps -ef | grep nginx`
and it returns info of nginx

```
root      6475  4292  0 16:58 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto nginx
nobody   31104 31334  0 Apr01 ?        00:00:13 nginx: worker process
root     31334     1  0 Jan25 ?        00:00:00 nginx: master process /usr/local/nginx-1.20.2/sbin/nginx -c /usr/local/nginx-1.20.2/conf/nginx.conf
```

how to restart this nginx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to do it

```
ps -ef|grep nginx
```

find process of nginx

then kill all these process

then

```
/usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx -c /usr/local/nginx-1.20.2/conf/nginx.conf
```

`-c /usr/local/nginx-1.20.2/conf/nginx.conf` is the config file option

Answer (score 0):

Seems, like you lost your nginx.service file (basically, located in /lib/systemd/system/nginx.service).
Try to reinstall nginx:

```
sudo apt-get purge nginx nginx-common nginx-full  
sudo apt-get install nginx
```